# MOSFET Gate Current Draw and Understanding Gate Driver IC Datasheets

Tags: mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I am building an ESC for a three phase BLDC motor based on the ST demo board STEVAL-ESC001V1.

For the given motor I have currently decided on using a Nexperia [PSMNR90-40SSH](https://www.nexperia.com/products/mosfets/power-mosfets/PSMNR90-40SSH.html) MOSFET.

Based on the Vishay document AN608A, Toshiba document "MOSFET Gate Drive Circuit", and TI document SLUA618A, I have been able to calculate the on and off times of this MOSFET using a 36 Ohm (external) gate resistor; ton working out to be approximately 269ns and toff being about 391ns.

Based on RC circuit theory, the peak gate current will be about 278mA (10V/36 Ohms @ t = 0s).  Based on the total gate charge (~110nC) the current required to charge the gate is 11nC/269ns = 408mA (based on my reading in the Toshiba document this would result in a 24 Ohm gate resistor).  Which value for gate current and resistance is correct to use?  Is my approach to calculating estimated switching times using the Vishay document correct?  Why do the numbers not line up?

Next I am reviewing the datasheet for the [L6398](https://www.st.com/en/power-management/l6398.html) gate driver IC from ST which is used on the demo board.  The datasheet states that this IC can source 290mA and sink 430mA (typical), and the minimum it can source/sink is 200mA/250mA.  How does ST derive these values, what do they mean, and how do I apply these values to the design I am working on?  How can this be a minimum value if these are short circuit currents?

It is rather overwhelming how much information is out there.  Could someone with experience designing such a circuit provide me with some guidance?

Comment: RC time constant does not work too well with mosfets as the apparent gate capacitance varies. Whilst you can tune the turn on/off times with the gate resistor, the resistor is mainly for stopping oscillation thus the term’gate stopper’. As for the datasheet specs - min and max are the expected production spread. Clearly the chip can only sink 250mA if the external conditions allow it.

Comment: I agree that gate capacitance is not linear, however the peak inrush current will always be your applied gate voltage divided by the gate resistance at time = 0 seconds.  The decay in the current just won't be the typical curve that dwindles out in 4-5 time constants.

Comment: To distill my first question; what is the industry best practice for calculating Ig?